# how to count rows when value change from value greater than threshold to 0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have three columns in dataframe , X1  X2  X3 , i want to count rows when value change from value greater than 1 to 0 .  if before 0 value less than 1 dont need to count.

input df:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'x1':[3,4,7,0,0,0,0,20,15,16,0,0,70],
             'X2':[3,4,7,0,0,0,0,20,15,16,0,0,70],
             'X3':[6,3,0.5,0,0,0,0,20,15,16,0,0,70]})

print(df1)



    x1  X2    X3
0    3   3   6.0
1    4   4   3.0
2    7   7   0.5
3    0   0   0.0
4    0   0   0.0
5    0   0   0.0
6    0   0   0.0
7   20  20  20.0
8   15  15  15.0
9   16  16  16.0
10   0   0   0.0
11   0   0   0.0
12  70  70  70.0
```

desired_output

```
   x1_count  X2_count  X3_count
0         6         6         2
```

Answer (score 1):

Idea is replace `0` to missing values, forward filling them, convert all another values to `NaN`s, compare greater like `1` and count `True`s by `sum` to `Series` converted to one row `DataFrame` with transpose:

```
m = df1.eq(0)

df2 = (df1.mask(m)
          .ffill()
          .where(m)
          .gt(1)
          .sum()
          .add_suffix('_count')
          .to_frame()
          .T
          )
print (df2)
   x1_count  X2_count  X3_count
0         6         6         2
```